# Setting Select Parameter = "" If User Doesn't Provide Input From Search Page

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to run a simple select statement, and then output the results to a GridView in ASP.NET/ C# WebForms.  The database I'm pulling from is a Microsoft SQL Server Database.

I'm trying to pass the variables received from user input from the search page to the results page through URL variables. I will then get them on the results page, and apply them to the query.  If the results page is loaded without going through the search page first, the query string, `From` will be undefined, and the results page will display everything in the dataset.

The problem I'm running into is with the `LastName`. Let's say `LastName` is optional in the search and may or may not be added. `FirstName` is required and the page cannot be submitted to the results page without it (for simplicity).  The results page however can be accessed without being submitted from the search page. In this case, we simply do a `select *` from the table and populate the gridview with the entire result set.

Code behind for results page:

```
string fromval = Request.QueryString["from"];
//checking to see if from is next, otherwise just run the regular select * query.  If from = next, URL Variables exist.  If URL Variables exist, we need to add them to the query.
if (fromval == "next")   
{
    //set variables from URL, sent from text boxes found on the search page
    string sfName = Request.QueryString["pfName"];
    string slName = Request.QueryString["plname"];
}

dsResults.SelectParameters.Add("FirstName", sfName.ToString());   
//we will never hit this code without providing first name, so we know it will always be there

if (slName != "")  //if last name was provided in the search box
{
    dsResults.SelectParameters.Add("LastName", slName.ToString());  
    //if I provide a value for last name, this works fine
}
else  
{
    //simply set the value of @LastName to "" so like will ignore it. 'WHERE LASTNAME Like ""' should allow every row.  Runs fine with LastName LIKE "" in SqlServer Mgt. Studio. 
    dsResults.SelectParameters.Add("LastName", "");
}

dsResults.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM [exampleTable] WHERE FirstName LIKE '%' + @FirstName + '%' AND LastName LIKE '%' + @LastName + '%';"

//check for a postback
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
    //bind the gridview data
    gvResults.DataSource = dsResults;
    gvResults.DataBind();
}
```

If I provide a value for Last Name in the URL, it runs fine with no problem, and gives the expected results.  If I don't, the query pulls nothing as if it's completely ignored.

Results page code simplified as much as possible:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvResults" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowDataBound="gvResults_RowDataBound" CssClass="table table-bordered">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName" SortExpression="FirstName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName" SortExpression="LastName" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

<!-- If the query is not changed in the code behind (happens when URL Variables Exist) then it simply selects * from the example table. -->
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsResults" runat="server" ConnectionString="myConnectionString" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [exampleTable]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Search page code simplified as much as possible:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequireFN" runat="server" ErrorMessage="First Name is required." ControlToValidate="txtFirstName"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtLastName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" OnClick="btnSearch_Click" text="Search" /></div>
```

Code behind for search page:

```
protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    Response.Redirect("ResultsPage.aspx?from=next&pfName=" + txtFirstName.Text + "&plName=" + txtLastName.Text);
}
```

I realize that this may not be the best way to go about this, and am open to other suggestions if you have any.

Thank you.

Comment: I appreciate you guys trying to help!  I was never able to get this figured out, and I kinda feel like I'm going down a dead end, so I think I'm going to abandon this idea, and try out some other ways of going about this.  I read somewhere that the AND statements might be able to be appended to the end of the query, if the URL variable exists, and I think that will probably be the best way to proceed.  SQL seems to behave differently in Visual Studio than it does in SSMS.  I think adding in empty strings in LIKE is always going to return nothing.  Regardless, I appreciate you guys trying!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
SELECT *
FROM [exampleTable]
WHERE FirstName LIKE '%' + @FirstName + '%' AND LastName LIKE '%' + @LastName + '%';
```

To this, where you bypass the LastName test when it is an empty string.

```
SELECT *
FROM [exampleTable]
WHERE FirstName LIKE '%' + @FirstName + '%' AND (coalesce(@LastName,'') = '' OR LastName LIKE '%' + @LastName + '%');
```

As an aside I recommend changing

```
dsResults.SelectParameters.Add("LastName", slName.ToString());
```

To the following where you fully specify the datatype and length rather than allowing them to be automatically determined. Doing it this way will avoid hard to find bugs and potentially improve performance.

```
dsResults.SelectParameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@LastName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 128) { Value = slName.ToString() });
```

Where you use the correct `SqlDbType` and length to match the column in your database.

You might also want to check that the LastName string provided isn't just a long series of spaces because that will also return no results to the user and could be confusing to them.

Comment: I appreciate your quick response!  I changed the code to be exactly as you provided, but my table is still not showing.  Is there a way to see the query results set outside of the table? (Would like to make sure the problem isn't something else).  Maybe something like WriteLine(results)? Still not getting any useful error messages, but I know for sure I'm making it to the else (LastName is empty) because I put a WriteLine in at the beginning of the else, and can see it in VS.  I appreciate the guidance on fully specifying the datatype!  Once I get this working, I will definitely apply this!

Comment: You test the query in SSMS. Example [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7fdda61694e25c23f2986fb5f54d715f).

Comment: @brandoonjen note I have just added `coalesce` to the blank test in case the automatic parameter is converting it to null.

Comment: Thanks Dale! I'm going to have to cut this off for today.  I've got some other obligations I have to take care of this evening that I unfortunately can't get out of. As of right now, I'm going to leave the question as is because I'm still not seeing the table, even after adding the coalesce section, and hoping someone else might point out something that I'm missing, but if I don't get this by tomorrow, I will mark  yours as the accepted answer.  I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

You may have missed NULLs and DBNULL.Value values.  This amplifies the previous answer a bit...

Please change:

```
if (fromval == "next")   
{
    //set variables from URL, sent from text boxes found on the search page
    string sfName = Request.QueryString["pfName"];
    string slName = Request.QueryString["plname"];
}
```

to read:

```
if (fromval == "next")   
{
    //set variables from URL, sent from text boxes found on the search page
    string sfName = Request.QueryString["pfName"];
    string slName = Request.QueryString["plname"];
}
if (!(sfName is string)) { sfName = ""; }
if (!(slName is string)) { slName = ""; }
```

And in case you have spaces as your whole string (unlikely from Request.QueryString), please change to:

```
dsResults.SelectParameters.Add("LastName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 128). value = slName.ToString().Trim();
```

-- no condition needed so eliminate the test on slName.

Finally, change the SQL to read like this...

```
dsResults.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM [exampleTable] WHERE FirstName LIKE '%' + @FirstName + '%' AND (@LastName = '' OR LastName LIKE '%' + @LastName + '%');"
```